# How do I create a background box for text, such as this one?

Tags: html, css

I'm new to HTML so excuse me if the question is stupid. I have tried to search but I haven't gotten the results I looked for.

Here is a link to the picture of what I'm looking for: https://i.gyazo.com/b2a8584eeb1841a71d023c605078f581.png

I don't know how to create such a yellow box (obviously through css, but more the box aspect, not color). Help?

Comment: `<p style="background:orange;padding: 1em;">text</p>`

Answer (score 3):

That kind of a box is essentially just a standard `<div>`.

```css
.alert {
  background-color: #ff9800;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="alert">
  <p>Warning: This website is in development.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you mean the placement on the (black) background. Here's one possibility:
The black background is the background of the body. The body has 100% width (which can be any value). Then there's a div with a margin (where the black background will be visible) and a padding (that creates space around he text) and an orange background.

Instead of giving the black background to the body you could also create a second DIV with those settings and wrap it around the first DIV as a parent element. This is useful especially if you want the black background NOT to coder the whole window, then you'd just make that outer DIV 80% wide (or whatever percentage or pixel value suits your needs) and give it a certain height (percentage or pixels).

```css
body {
  background: black;
  height: 100%;
}

.x {
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
  background: orange;
  line-height: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<div class="x">
  Warning: This website is in development.
</div>
```